# BootstrapValidator with Portfolio Gallery in HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't make to work my boostrapValidator with portfolio filters gallery. 
On click on a filter in gallery, nothing happens. When I comment js/bootstrapValidator.js then it works.

Here are problematic code:

```
<head>
<!-- CSS -->
<link href="css/test/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/test/bootstrapvalidator/bootstrapValidator.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/test/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-responsive.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrapValidator.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vertical-rhythm.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/telmask/intlTelInput.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/YTPlayer.css">    

</head>
        <!-- Portfolio Section -->
    <section class="page-section pb-0" id="portfolio">
        <div class="relative">

            <h2 class="section-title font-alt mb-70 mb-sm-40">
                Apartments
            </h2>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

                        <div class="section-text align-center mb-70 mb-xs-40">

                            In&nbsp;auctor ex&nbsp;id&nbsp;urna faucibus porttitor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In&nbsp;maximus ligula semper metus pellentesque mattis. Maecenas volutpat, diam enim sagittis quam, id&nbsp;porta quam. Sed id&nbsp;dolor
                            consectetur fermentum nibh volutpat, accumsan purus.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Works Filter -->
            <div class="works-filter font-alt align-center">
                <a href="#" class="filter active" data-filter="*">All images</a>
                <a href="#branding" class="filter" data-filter=".branding">Apartment 1</a>
                <a href="#design" class="filter" data-filter=".design">Apartment 2</a>
                <a href="#photography" class="filter" data-filter=".photography">Mountain</a>
            </div>
            <!-- End Works Filter -->

            <!-- Works Grid -->
            <ul class="works-grid work-grid-3 work-grid-gut clearfix font-alt hover-white hide-titles" id="work-grid">

                <!-- Work Item (Lightbox) -->
                <li class="work-item mix design">
                    <a href="images/1140x642/image1140_1.jpg" class="work-lightbox-link mfp-image">
                        <div class="work-img">
                            <img src="images/650x418/image650_1.jpg" alt="Work" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="work-intro">
                            <h3 class="work-title">Lobby</h3>
                            <div class="work-descr">
                                Only a few steps to paradise!
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <!-- End Work Item -->

                <!-- Work Item (External Page) -->
                <li class="work-item mix photography branding">
                    <a href="images/1140x642/image1140_3.jpg" class="work-lightbox-link mfp-image">
                        <div class="work-img">
                            <img src="images/650x418/image650_3.jpg" alt="Work" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="work-intro">
                            <h3 class="work-title"></h3>
                            <div class="work-descr">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <!-- End Work Item -->

                <!-- Work Item (External Page) -->
                <li class="work-item mix photography">
                    <a href="images/1140x642/image1140_4.jpg" class="work-lightbox-link mfp-image">
                        <div class="work-img">
                            <img src="images/650x418/image650_4.jpg" alt="Work" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="work-intro">
                            <h3 class="work-title"></h3>
                            <div class="work-descr">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <!-- End Work Item -->

                <!-- Work Item (External Page) -->
                <li class="work-item mix photography">
                    <a href="images/1140x642/image1140_5.jpg" class="work-lightbox-link mfp-image">
                        <div class="work-img">
                            <img src="images/650x418/image650_5.jpg" alt="Work" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="work-intro">
                            <h3 class="work-title">Portrait</h3>
                            <div class="work-descr">
                                Lightbox
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <!-- End Work Item -->

                <!-- Work Item (Lightbox) -->
                <li class="work-item mix photography">
                    <a href="images/1140x642/image1140_6.jpg" class="work-lightbox-link mfp-image">
                        <div class="work-img">
                            <img src="images/650x418/image650_6.jpg" alt="Work" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="work-intro">
                            <h3 class="work-title">Portrait</h3>
                            <div class="work-descr">
                                Lightbox
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <!-- End Work Item -->

            </ul>
            <!-- End Works Grid -->

        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- End Portfolio Section -->

                <!-- Contact Form -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <form class="form contact-form" role="form" id="form-div" method="post" action="">
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <div class="cf-left-col">
                                <!-- Check In Date -->
                                <div class="form-group required">
                                    <input type="text" id="checkIn" type="text" class="input-md round form-control datepickstart" placeholder="Check-in" name="checkindate" onkeypress="return false" />
                                </div>
                                <!-- Check Out Date -->
                                <div class="form-group required">
                                    <input type="text" id="checkOut" type="text" class="input-md round form-control datepickend" placeholder="Check-out" name="checkoutdate" onkeypress="return false" />
                                </div>
                                <!-- Name -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="input-md round form-control" placeholder="Name" pattern=".{3,100}">
                                </div>
                                <!-- Mobile phone -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="tel" name="mobile" id="mobile" class="mobile input-md round form-control" placeholder="Mobile">
                                </div>
                                <!-- Email -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="input-md round form-control" placeholder="Email" pattern=".{5,100}">
                                </div>
                                <!-- Number of adults -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="person" id="inputGuests" class="person input-md round form-control" placeholder="Guests">
                                </div>
                                <!-- Number of children -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="child" id="inpoutChildren" class="person input-md round form-control" placeholder="Children">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cf-right-col">
                                <!-- Message -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea name="message" id="message" class="input-md round form-control" style="height: 84px;" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Send Button -->
                                <div class="align-right pt-10">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <!-- <button class="submit_btn btn btn-mod btn-medium btn-round" id="submit_btn">Submit Message</button> -->
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit_btn">Send reservation</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <div class="cf-left-col">
                                <!-- Inform Tip -->
                                <!-- <div class="form-tip pt-20">
                                    <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> All the fields are required
                                </div> -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="cf-right-col">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="result"></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Contact Form -->

    <!-- JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/telmask/intlTelInput.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/telmask/utils.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/SmoothScroll.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.localScroll.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.viewport.mini.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.countTo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.appear.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=***********************************"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/gmap3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.simple-text-rotator.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ajaxchimp.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.backgroundvideo.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test/bootstrapvalidator/bootstrapValidator.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test/autonumeric.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test/main.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 10]><script type="text/javascript" src="js/placeholder.js"></script><![endif]-->

 </body>

 </html>
```

If anyone knows I would be grateful.
I do not know for any other validation library (jquery.validate.js) samples are not working on GutHub on my computer (Chrome)

Comment: Any errors in the console when boostrapValidator.js is active?

Comment: @reporter, On click filter in gallery I get in console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (main.js:281)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3) Line 281 in main.js is a function:$(function() {
        $('a[href*=#]').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top }, 500, 'linear');
        });
    });When I comment this function, now it works!

Comment: Either there is a conflic bettween included libraries or the syntax of gallery object is wrong (for bootstrapValidator.js). You have to figure out - step by step, which object generates this error message, by comment in each object.